# Is there an equivalent of the Task.ContinueWith operator in Rx?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Is there an equivalent of the Task.ContinueWith operator in Rx?

I'm using Rx with Silverlight,  I am making two webservice calls with the FromAsyncPattern method, and I'd like to do them *synchronously*.

```
        var o1 = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<int, string>(client.BeginGetData, client.EndGetData);
        var o2 = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<int, string>(client.BeginGetData, client.EndGetData);
```

Is there an operator (like Zip) that will only start / subscribe to o2 *only after* o1 returns Completed?
I handle failure of either web service call the same way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's called projection:

```
o1().SelectMany(_ => o2()).Subscribe();
```

Comment: I set breakpoints in client.BeginGetData and EndGetData and added an artifical delay in the web service.  BeginGetData gets called twice before EndGetData is reached.

Comment: They are coming back on separate threads so the debugger will display nondeterministic results, this is indeed the correct answer

Comment: @foson, you should set breakpoint inside SelectMany and check that EndGetData for first operation is already called.

Comment: My mistake was that I was passing the arguments to the Func returned by Observable.FromAsyncPattern before my select statement and selecting the resulting IObservable.  I see now you must only pass the argument within the SelectMany.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

While Alex is right, the other way you can do this is:

```
Observable.Concat(
    o1(4),
    o2(6))
  .Subscribe(x => /* Always one, then two */);
```

Which guarantees that o2 only runs after o1 - as opposed to Merge, which would run them at the same time:

```
Observable.Merge(
    o1(4),
    o2(6))
  .Subscribe(x => /* Either one or two */);
```

Comment: If you don't need to combine the result from operation A with operation B somehow, I prefer .Concat. I think it's semantically more clear. If you need to combine observable results (like passing the result from A into the call that results in B), then projection is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I agree that Concat is clearer,  but I'll probably go with select/SelectMany in my real world usage since my webservices will be returning different types and with SelectMany I can process both returned values in one call of my onNext handler.