# How to send pre request before every request in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, httprequest

I want to send one pre request to my server before send every request. From that pre request I will receive the token from my server and than I have to add that token into all the request. This is the process.

I have try with some methods to achieve this. But I am facing one problem. That is, When I try to send pre request, it is processing with the current request. That mean both request going parallel.

I want to send pre request first and parse the response. After parsing the pre request response only I want to send that another request. But first request not waiting for the pre request response. Please let me any way to send pre request before all the request.

**This is my code:**

***ViewModel:***

```
`public class ListExampleViewModel
    {
        SecurityToken sToken = null;
        public ListExampleViewModel()
        {
            GlobalConstants.isGetToken = true;
            var listResults = REQ_RESP.postAndGetResponse((new ListService().GetList("xx","xxx")));

            listResults.Subscribe(x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n..................................2");
                Console.WriteLine("Received Response==>" + x);
            });
        }
    }`
```

**Constant Class for Request and Response:**

```
`public class REQ_RESP
    {
        private static string receivedAction = "";
        private static string receivedPostDate = "";


        public static IObservable<string> postAndGetResponse(String postData)
        {
            if (GlobalConstants.isGetToken)
            {
    //Pre Request for every reusest               
                receivedPostDate = postData;
                GlobalConstants.isGetToken = false;
                getServerTokenMethod();
                postData = receivedPostDate;
            }

            HttpWebRequest serviceRequest =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(Constants.SERVICE_URI));


            var fetchRequestStream =
                 Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Stream>(serviceRequest.BeginGetRequestStream,
                                                                 serviceRequest.EndGetRequestStream);
            var fetchResponse =
                Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(serviceRequest.BeginGetResponse,
                                                            serviceRequest.EndGetResponse);

            Func<Stream, IObservable<HttpWebResponse>> postDataAndFetchResponse = st =>
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(st) as StreamWriter)
                {
                    writer.Write(postData);
                    writer.Close();
                }
                return fetchResponse().Select(rp => (HttpWebResponse)rp);
            };

            Func<HttpWebResponse, IObservable<string>> fetchResult = rp =>
            {
                if (rp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {

                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(rp.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        reader.Close();
                        rp.GetResponseStream().Close();
                        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(result);
                        Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
                        return Observable.Return<string>(result);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var msg = "HttpStatusCode == " + rp.StatusCode.ToString();
                    var ex = new System.Net.WebException(msg,
                        WebExceptionStatus.ReceiveFailure);
                    return Observable.Throw<string>(ex);
                }

            };

            return
                from st in fetchRequestStream()
                from rp in postDataAndFetchResponse(st)
                from str in fetchResult(rp)
                select str;
        }

        public static void getServerTokenMethod()
        {
            SecurityToken token = new SecurityToken();

            var getTokenResults = REQ_RESP.postAndGetResponse((new ServerToken().GetServerToken()));

            getTokenResults.Subscribe(x =>
            {
                ServerToken serverToken = new ServerToken();
                ServiceModel sm = new ServiceModel();
    //Parsing Response
                serverToken = extract(x, sm);
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.NetErrorCode)))
                {
        MessageBox.Show("Show Error Message");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n..................................1");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nserverToken.token==>" + serverToken.token);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nserverToken.pk==>" + serverToken.pk);                   
                }
            },
            ex =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception = " + ex.Message);
            },
            () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End of Process.. Releaseing all Resources used.");
            });
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's couple options:

You could replace the Reactive Extensions model with a simpler async/await -model for the web requests using [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) (you also need [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) in WP7). With HttpClient your code would end up looking like this:

**Request and Response:**

```
        public static async Task<string> postAndGetResponse(String postData)
    {
        if (GlobalConstants.isGetToken)
        {
            //Pre Request for every reusest               
            await getServerTokenMethod();
        }

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var postMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(Constants.SERVICE_URI));
        var postResult = await client.SendAsync(postMessage);

        var stringResult = await postResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return stringResult;
    }
```

**Viewmodel:**

```
    public class ListExampleViewModel
{
    SecurityToken sToken = null;
    public ListExampleViewModel()
    {
        GetData();
    }

    public async void GetData()
    {
        GlobalConstants.isGetToken = true;
        var listResults = await REQ_RESP.postAndGetResponse("postData");
    }
}
```

Another option is, if you want to continue using Reactive Extensions, to look at RX's Concat-method. With it you could chain the token request and the actual web request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6754558/66988

Comment: Hi I try to follow your first option. But I can not do that. I am facing some error.
`The type or namespace name 'async' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. I am searching for the solution for this error. And I found one answer [From this Link].(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557032/how-to-use-async-with-visual-studio-2010-and-net-4-0). I conclude myself this is not possible. 

Now I am trying with your second option. But I don't know where I have to add that methods. If possible please let me any way to solve my problem.

Comment: Hi @Mikael Koskinen.. Finally I found the solution. I used **o1().SelectMany(_ => o2()).Subscribe();** for my solution and do somw changes in my code. Now I can send pre request..!!
Thanks you very much..